# Why are specificity and sensitivity (recall) inversely related?

Tags: classification, sensitivity-specificity

I remember learning this about medical tests when I studied biochemistry and now I met with this rule again by learning about binary classification and PR-curves. If we check the equations for both concept:

```
precision = tp/(tp+fp)
recall = tp/(tp+fn)
```

the false positive and false negative must be inversely related, or otherwise our rule wasn't be true. Is there a theory which explains this relationship between false negatives and false positives?

Comment: Your definitions are switched.

Comment: Your "precision" is the positive predictive value calculation, not sepcificity (tn/(tn+fp).

Comment: @Todd I got the definition from here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-Precision-Recall-PR-curve Do you think it is not a valid source?

Comment: @inf3rno Since quora is published on the internet, and there are a multitude of high-quality scholarly resources that are also published on the internet, it's hard to think of a situation where using Quora for information about a technical definition is preferable to a scholarly publication.